# slideDown/slideUp make other item hidden in a faq list

Tags: jquery, slidedown, slideup

slideDown/slideUp make other item hidden in a list, but the request is hidden the answer only after clicking the corresponding question.

There is always a style--height: 0; added to answer block automatically somehow by jquery.

How to remove or overwrite the code?

Comment: What you had tried to do this,can post your code.

Comment: show us your afford.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$('.slidedown_head').click(function(){
   $(this).next('.slidedown_body').slideToggle(); 


});
```

[**Live Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/SzQwS/17/)

Hope it helps you

Answer (score 0):

not the nicest way but you can always add a "!important" after a css rule

```
.cssclass{height:10px!important;}
```

this cant be overrided anymore so dont use it for everything..